# Maven. Сборка JavaFx проекта

Tags: java, javafx, maven

Собираю проект в .jar с помощью zenjava javafx-maven-plugin. В конечной папке создается сам .jar'ник и папка lib со всеми зависимостями.

В проекте есть несколько папок с файлами конфигурации, которые "запаковываются" в сам .jar'ник. Мне же, в свою очередь, хотелось бы эти папки "вынести" из .jar файла, чтобы пользователь мог с ними работать. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом надо сконфигурировать pom.xml для этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <additionalAppResources>src/main/deploy/other</additionalAppResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

После того как разобрались с упаковкой ресурсов в jar-ку, additionalAppResources - указывает папку, откуда файлы будут скопированы в папку рядом с jar.[см. на Github](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zenjava/javafx/maven/plugin/NativeMojo.java#L210)

Comment: Я так понимаю, при этом мне придется данные ресурсы перенести в другую папку в проекте и при этом в resource-plugin'e явно указать на них ссылку?

Comment: Я бы resource-plugin'ом сложил их в папку где-то в target, из которой потом их заберет javafx-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на анлгоязычной версии. Не все моменты понял, но работает. Точнее, работает, но без участия javafx-maven-plugin, т.е. каким образом это собрать в native я не знаю.

Вот настройки плагинов для реализации данного сценария:

```
<plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.jar.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- директория, куда скидываются все необходимые файлы -->
                <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>folder1/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>folder2/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>folder3/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>path.to.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.resources.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <!-- копируем файлы ресурсов в ${distrib.directory} -->
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}/conf</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>folder1/**</include>
                                    <include>folder2/**</include>
                                    <include>folder3/**</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${plugin.dependency.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${distrib.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                    <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                    <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.javafx.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>path.to.Main</mainClass>
                <vendor>super_corp</vendor>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
```